# Evaluation of variable through Pass By Name

Tags: history, pass-by-name, algol

I have a doubt regarding Pass By Name

```
   Procedure test ( int c, int d) 
    { 
      int k = 10;

      c = 5;

      d = d + 2 ;

      k = c + d;

      print (k);
}

main()
{
    k = 1;

    test(k,k);

    print (k);
}
```

I did refer to one of the earlier question on [what is  pass by name and how does it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838079/what-is-pass-by-name-and-how-does-it-work-exactly)

and the link given in it :

[Pass by name parameter passing](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html)

The Question i have is : will the above code print : ( 14 , 1 ) or (14, 14)

Basically doubt is whether the value of k in procedure be reflected in main procedure or not.

I'm preparing for an exam. This's a code snippet given in one of the question bank.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by name, when you are passing a variable and not a more complex expression, behaves the same as pass by reference.  Thus, your code prints 14 and 7.

Note that the local variable `k` in your procedure `test` is not the same variable as the global variable `k`.  In `test`, the assignments `c = 5` and `d = d + 2` both assign to the global `k`, as it was passed by name to `test` through both `c` and `d`.  Thus, after these assignments, the global `k` has the value `7`.  The assignment `k = c + d;` affects the local variable `k` (as that is the `k` in scope at that time), not the global variable `k` (which is shadowed by the local variable), and thus the global `k` retains the value `7` after the assignment.

Comment: Hey thanks ibid that was really helpful. So here pass by name behaves  like pass by reference.