# Pass-by-name implementation in C

Tags: c, parameters, pass-by-name

I know that C uses pass-by-value and we can emulate pass-by-reference with the help of pointers. But, for example, in order to calculate a simple mathematical expression, how do I implement pass-by-name (which is kind of lazy evaluation but not exactly) in C?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by pass by name, and how is that different from pass by value, and pass by reference

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Well, rather not. search here.

Comment: Never heard of it myself, but LMGTFY gave me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838079/what-is-pass-by-name-and-how-does-it-work-exactly

Comment: @pheonix  Please let us knopw why pass-by-value thr' a pointer does no suffice your needs. :)

Comment: Also, in your case, is _implement_ == _emulate_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, exactly emulating, sorry.

Comment: You use the right tool for the job. Which is, if you need pass by name, something other than C.

Comment: C does not support pass by reference. Your prerequisite is wrong.

Comment: C is turing complete, so "how to implement it?" - By writing code.

Comment: @Olaf , what I mean is emulating.

Comment: Emulating writing code? Anyway, don't get too fancy. If you want such features, use a language which is suited for this, e.g. Python.

Comment: @Olaf Of course I can do this with Python, but I want to learn to do this in C. I am studying computer science, I do not expect you to do my assignments, but help me learning the process.

Comment: The standard term is "call by name".  It is best known from Algol 60, and classically implemented using objects known as "thunks".  Basically, arguments are evaluated when the called function accesses them, as many times as they are accessed, in the context of the caller.  Probably the closest you can get in C would be to pass functions which are called by the function each time the argument is needed.

Comment: It might be possible to implement this using the gcc extension which supports nested functions, which could then be passed as arguments.  The caller would then call the functions when it needs the arguments.  But this is not portable and is not true C, so it would only work with gcc with the extension enabled.  I suppose you could instead use structures that contain both data pointers and function pointers.  It's ugly no matter how you do it.

Comment: Call by name example:  You call a function `foo(i, a[i])`.  Function `foo` is declared `void foo(int x, int y)`.  With call by name, if `foo` assigns 5 to `x`, then accesses `y`, it will end up getting `a[5]`, since `i` is now 5 in the caller.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've got the point, thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that the C preprocessor uses something pretty close to pass by name.  For example, if we say `#define foo(x, y) (x=5, printf("%d\n", y))`, then invoke `foo(i, a[i])`, it'll do just what @TomKarzes described.

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html .

Answer (score 3):

C is only pass-by-value. You can't pass by reference or name. With the pre-processor you can do various hacks but not in the C language.

Sometimes, people call passing a pointer "pass-by-reference" but this is not the case. The pointer is passed by value like anything else. C++ is a different story but you asked about C.

You might also be interested in [this article discussion this at length](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/)

Comment: _You can't implement pass-by-reference_, sorry, but isn't it too negative?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can emulate pass-by-reference by using pointers.

Comment: #offtopic: `C is only pass-by-value`..I was unaware... I thought C is a language.. :P

Comment: thanks both, no idea why I wrote "you can't implement". The implement is not necessary and might even be misleading.

Comment: Of course you can implement pass-by reference. The question is what it applies to. Given `void func (int* x)`, the pointer address is passed by value, but the pointed-at data is passed by reference. Otherwise if you want to be picky, computers can only pass addresses to functions by putting values on the stack or in index registers. No pass by reference exists anywhere inside a computer.

Comment: Note OP changed the question, which renders part of your answer useless.

Comment: I have corrected the misleading part of the question. What I need is an example of pass-by-name emulation using C (I think macros may be useful, but I have no idea..)

Comment: @phoeNix: *Tom Karzes* explained the concept here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026187/pass-by-name-implementation-in-c#comment61603043_37026187. Now it's up to *you* to implement it. If running into *specific* issues while doing so, feel free come back here asking another question on it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter substitution used by function-like preprocessor macros is sometimes described as being "pass by name".

Comment: Do you have any example demonstrating that? For example, subtracting two variables? I have tried thunking but I could not work it out..

Answer (score 0):

An example of "pass-by-name" in C preprocessor is: #define PROD(X,Y) ((X)*(Y)). The substitution is textual, so the extra parenthesis pairs inside is needed. In fact, #define PROD(X,Y) (X*Y) when called this way: PROD(A+B) instead of ((A+B)*(A+B)) would produce (A+B*A+B), which is not mathematically equivalent.