# Not understanding slices and pointers

Tags: go, pointers, slice

Current project has me taking a struct (with annotation tags) and writing the data out as a flat file.  This file is a columnar file so the positioning of the data is important.  These positions and lengths are set up in my struct tags at the field level.

The issue i am having is, i am passing the pointer to my []byte result slice to my functions, but no matter what i do, the original slice is not housing the data.  Here is a brief sample code that demonstrates what i am doing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func writeInt(value int, fieldData *[]byte, col, length int) {
    v := fmt.Sprintf("%+0" + strconv.Itoa(length) +"d", value)
    copyData(fieldData, v, col, length)
}

func writeString(value string, fieldData *[]byte, col, length int) {
    v := fmt.Sprintf("%-" + strconv.Itoa(length) + "s", value)
    copyData(fieldData, v, col, length)
}

func copyData(fieldData *[]byte, v string, col, length int) {
    data := *fieldData
    if len(data) < col + length {
        temp := make([]byte, col + length - 1)
        copy(temp, data)
        data = temp
    }
    copy(data[col - 1:length], v)
    fieldData = &data
}

func main() {
    var results []byte

    writeInt(13, &results, 1, 3)
    writeString("TEST", &results, 4, 10)

    fmt.Print(results)

}
```

Expected result (as string) should be:

```
'013TEST      ' - zero pad in front of int and space pad behind string
```

But i am getting []

Am i looking at this entirely wrong, or am i just not understanding something?

Comment: `fieldData = &data` does the opposite of what you want: it overwrites the local variable `fieldData` with a pointer to the local variable `data`. What you want is more likely `*fieldData = data`, overwriting *the memory pointed to* by `fieldData` with the data in `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note beforehand:** Do not use pointers to slices (slices are already small headers pointing to a backing array). You may modify the elements without a pointer, and if you need to modify the header (e.g. append elements to it), return the new slice, just like the builtin `append()` does.

Also what you try to do is much easier achievable with the [`bytes.Buffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer) type. It implements `io.Writer`, you can directly write into it (even using `fmt.Fprint()`), and obtain its content either as a `[]byte` or as a `string`.

---

Every parameter is a copy of the passed value. Modifying parameters only modifies this copy.

If you do:

```
fieldData = &data
```

Even though `fieldData` is a pointer, you're just modifying the copy. You must modify the *pointed* value:

```
*fieldData = data
```

Printing the results:

```
fmt.Println(results)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(results))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/clu-KKo6uKR)):

```
[43 49 51 84 69 83 84 32 32 32 0 0 0]
"+13TEST   \x00\x00\x00"
```

Answer (score 0):

See [icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884987/1256452), and particularly the "note beforehand" section, for your *specific case*.  For a general discussion of pointers, read on; note that only some of this is specific to Go itself.

What a pointer does for you is to give you a *level of indirection*.  Some languages—Go included—use a "pass by value" mechanism, where regardless of whether you pass a constant value or a variable to some function:

```
f(3)
```

or:

```
f(x)
```

the function `f` receives the *value*, not the *name of the variable* or anything remotely like that.  (Other languages are different, having "pass by name",<sup>1</sup> "pass by reference", or "value-result" semantics in some cases.  See also [Why [do] so many languages [use pass] by value?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/153474/225719)  The fact that `f` receives the value, not the variable's name or anything like that, is helpful when there *isn't* a variable, as in the `f(3)` case, or for:

```
f(x + y)
```

where we have to do a summation first and hence there's no *single* variable involved.

Now, in Go in particular, functions can and very often do have multiple return values:

```
func g(a int) (bool, int, error) { ... }
```

so if we want to be able to *update* something, we can just write:

```
ok, x, err = g(x)
```

which gathers all three values, including the updated `x`, right where we want it.  But this does expose the details of the updated `x`, and/or maybe it is inconvenient.  If we want to give some function *permission* to *change* some value(s) stored in some variable, we can define our function to take a *pointer to* that variable:

```
func g2(a *int) (bool, error) { ... }
```

Now instead of `ok, x, err = g(x)` we can write `ok, err = g2(&x)`.

This is not much of an improvement at all, for this particular case.  But suppose instead of a simple `int`, `x` is now a structure with a bunch of complicated state, e.g., something that will read input from a series of files, switching to the next file automatically:

```
x := multiFileReader(...)
```

Now if we want parts of the multi-file-reader to be able to access various fields in whatever structure `x` represents, we can make `x` itself a pointer variable, pointing to the `struct`.  Then:

```
str, err := readNextString(x)
```

passes a pointer (because `x` *is* a pointer) which allows `readNextString` to update some of the fields within `x`.  (This same general logic applies if `x` is a method, e.g, an `io.Reader`, but in this case we start using `interface`, which adds a bunch of additional wrinkles.  I'm ignoring those here to concentrate on the pointer aspect.)

#### Adding indirection adds complexity

When we do this sort of thing—pass a *pointer value pointing to the original variable*, where the original variable itself holds some initial or intermediate value and we update it as we go along—the function that *receives* this pointer value now has a variable of type *pointer to T* for some type *T*.  This extra variable *is* a *variable*.  That means we can assign a new value into it.  If and when we do so, we lose the original value:

```
func g2(a *int) (bool, error) {
    ... section 1: do stuff with `*a` ...
    var another int
    a = &another
    ... section 2: do more stuff with `*a` ...
    return ok, err
}
```

In section 1, `a` *points to*, and `*a` thus *refers to*, whatever variable some caller passed to `g2`.  Making changes to `*a` will show up there.  But in section 2, `a` points to `another`, and `*a` is initially zero (because `another` is zero).  Making changes to `*a` here *won't* show up in the caller.

You can, if you like, avoid using `*a` directly:

```
func g2(a *int) (bool, error) {
    b := *a
    p := &b
    var ok bool
    // presumably there's a `var err error` or equivalent too
    for attempts := 0; !ok && attempts < 5; attempts++ {
        ... do things ...
        ... if things are working well, set ok = true and set p = a ...
        ... update *p ...
    }
    return ok, err
}
```

Sometimes this is the sort of thing you want: if things *aren't* going well we carefully *don't* overwrite `*a` by overwriting `b` instead, but if things *are* going well we overwrite `*a` by having `p` point to `a` in the "update *p" section.  But it's tougher to reason about: make sure you're getting a very clear benefit before you resort to this sort of thing.

And of course, if we have a pointer to some variable stored in a variable, we can take a pointer to *that* variable too: `i := 3; a := &i; pa := &a`.  That gives us the opportunity to yet add another level of indirection, `ppa := &pa`, which gives us another opportunity, and so on.  It's <s>turtles all the way down</s> pointers all the way up, except at the very end where we must have some sort of final answer like `i`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Pass-by-name is particularly tricky, and not very common; see [What is "pass-by-name" and how does it work exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838079/1256452)  But it did lead to a great joke that Niklaus Wirth used to tell about himself, that some would say "Nick-louse Veert" and hence call him by name, and others would say "Nickle's Worth" and hence call him by value.  (I think I heard this one second hand—I don't think he ever came to the U when I was there.)